# How to avoid an Access Violation when adding a destructor to a DataModule?

Tags: c++builder

Using C++Builder, I created a new project, added a DataModule to the project, added a reference to that DataModule in the MainForm.  I ran it and closed the MainForm.  Result – no problem.

Then, I added a destructor to the DataModule, recompiled, and it ran fine until I closed the MainForm, and then I got an Access Violation.

What does it take to be able to add a destructor to a DataModule?

Here is the code I came up with:

DataMod2.h

```
#ifndef DataMod2H
#define DataMod2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TDataModule2 : public TDataModule
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TDataModule2(TComponent* Owner);
    ~TDataModule2();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TDataModule2 *DataModule2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

DataMod2.cpp

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include "DataMod2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma classgroup "FMX.Controls.TControl"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TDataModule2 *DataModule2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TDataModule2::TDataModule2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TDataModule(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TDataModule2::~TDataModule2() {

}
```

Unit2.h

```
#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
#include "DataMod2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
    TDataModule2 * dataMod;
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Unit2.cpp

```
#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    dataMod = new TDataModule2(Form1);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the base class destructor requires matching the entire signature of the destructor, including the calling convention.  The DataModule derives from `TObject`, and `TObject`'s destructor looks like this:

```cpp
__fastcall virtual ~TObject();
```

Your DataModule destructor is missing the `__fastcall` calling convention:

```cpp
class TDataModule2 : public TDataModule
{
    ...
    __fastcall ~TDataModule2();
};
```

```cpp
__fastcall TDataModule2::~TDataModule2() {

}
```

Also, in your `TForm1` constructor, you should be using the `this` pointer as the DataModule's `Owner` rather than using the global `Form1` variable:

```cpp
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    dataMod = new TDataModule2(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Remy! A long time ago I ran into some object that I was getting compiler warnings saying that the destructor didn't need the __fastcall calling convention, so I took that as meaning never put it in.  You have taught me something new to me today.  Thank you.